# Going from an Individualized Masters to PhD?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, research-topic, early-career

I'm about to finish my Bachelors in History, I'm currently in a exchange as a research intern and I was suggested by my research director to do a Masters in a Individualized Program, as my interest of research is interdisciplinary (Oral history, geography/urbanism, agriculture/environment). After speaking with a teacher who works in similar topics he told me that it could be harder to me to get into a PhD after doing and INDI, as I wouldn't have a Masters background in History. I want to do a PhD and keep researching, but I really want to be working in a more interdisciplinary and holistic way. Any views? Experiences? Have any of you done a PhD after an INDI?

Comment: What will be different about your masters program of study as compared to one in history?

Comment: Instead of taking just history courses I'd take courses in geography and environment, I would take just methodology courses in history, thus I wouldn't have the whole history background.